# Подписывание даты через HMAC с SHA256

Tags: python, python-3.x, hmac

День добрый.

Есть код:

```
import requests
import hashlib
import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
import hmac
import base64

newdategmt= strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %X GMT', gmtime())

y= 'Bearer '+(hmac.new(b'123123123123', msg=(newdategmt.encode('ascii')),    digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

Создание времени в определенном формате, попытка его закодировать в SHA256 с помощью секретного ключа и выдача в нормальном виде.
Возникает ошибка:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Подскажите, почему алгоритм не может закодировать строку?
При изменении типа:

```
newdategmt1=[newdategmt]
```

Тоже выдаёт ошибку:

> TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

Comment: Добавьте минимальный код, чтобы можно было запустить. Сейчас нужно будет каждому желающему импортировать strftime, gmtime, hmac и т.п.

Comment: Потому что нельзя складывать символы с байтами, а вы складываете

Comment: «При изменении типа» — ну да, считать sha256 от списка это уже просто абсурд, sha256 (и hmac) работает с байтами, а не со списками

Comment: Но проблема в том, что он байты строки тоже не хочет определять.

Comment: `'Bearer '` не является байтовой строкой

Comment: Ок, если выполнить сначала кодирование, потом преобразование в строку, а потом уже сложить с Bearer - должно получиться?

Comment: Собственно gil9red именно это и предложил в ответе. Только, похоже, `.digest()` стоит заменить на `.hexdigest()`, а вообще вы до сих пор воспроизводимый пример не предоставили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import hashlib
import hmac

from datetime import datetime


dategmt = datetime.now().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %X GMT')

digest = hmac.new(b'123123123123', msg=(dategmt.encode('ascii')), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
y = 'Bearer ' + digest
print(y)  # Bearer
```

Результат:

```
df47b42971fba32b355356c240d0e0b9f5b59b155e93dfbd41ea94adcebc5e9a
```

Comment: > y = 'Bearer ' + digest.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @Артем, а теперь?